# How to decode the URL with encoded Query String

Tags: swift3

say, I have below Encoded URL:

```
let urlString = "https://www.sky.com/api/v1/rest/level2/in-in/?q=a%23+nunit+mac&q=c%23+nunit+mac&ap=裕坊%20邻坊
```

**Problem:**

```
let decodedString = urlString.removingPercentEncoding!
```

But this method removing % but not decode it.

For above example: `a%23+nunit`, after decode , it should be: `a# nunit` but it show : `a#+nunit`

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: There is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is correct. `%23` percent decodes to `#` and that's what you got. There is nothing about percent decoding that promises to treat + in a special way, so it remains. If you want to do something special with +, go ahead.

Comment: Can you help to provide a solution? Thanks

Comment: Got it, thank for the explanation. I need to use another func to replace the '+' with " ".

Comment: To explain what's going on, it is common to encode " " as `+` for legacy reasons dating to before percent encoding was common. Even Google still encodes "test query" as `test+query` and "plus+" as `plus%2B`, even though `test%2Bquery` and `plus+` would be more correct.